# https request, returns not found, in VM of GCP even though the api endpoint exists

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to call and endpoint via `python requests module` using `post method`, this works just fine in my local machine but when I try to run the same exact code in a `compute engine virtual machine` in the `GCP` I get a response `404 not found`

```
requests.post('https/url/which/exists', data='some_string', headers={necessary headers})
```

Are there any restrictions on that in the cloud?

if I print the `response.__dict__` I get the following:

```
{'_next': None, 'encoding': None, 'connection': <requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter object at 0x7f3036ed99b0>, '_content_consumed': True, 'cookies': <RequestsCookieJar[]>, 'history': [], 'reason': 'Not Found', 'headers': {'Connection': 'close', 'X-FRAME-OPTIONS': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'APIm-Debug-Trans-Id, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-Global-Transaction-ID', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000', 'Pragma': 'no-cache\r\n Cache-Control: no-store', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'application/xml', 'Expires': '0', 'X-Backside-Transport': 'FAIL FAIL'}, 'elapsed': datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 912545), 'url': 'https://m01.api.edp.com/edp/web-services-qa/INVOICING/UtilitiesTimeSeriesCalculationBulkCreateConfirmation', 'raw': <urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f3036e6de80>, 'status_code': 404, 'request': <PreparedRequest [POST]>, '_content': b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<errorResponse>\n  <httpCode>404</httpCode>\n  <httpMessage>Not Found</httpMessage>\n  <moreInformation>No resources match requested URI</moreInformation>\n</errorResponse>'}
```

Comment: From the virtual machine if you ping the site it works?

Comment: I tried to ping and I get `Name or service not known`

Comment: I tried to do it using curl and it worked

Comment: So you cannot ping it but curl succeeds?